# How secured an api rest symfony?

Tags: rest, api, symfony, security

Good evening to all, I hope that to go to you all well, I come towards you to wonder how reassured(secured) an api rest, of the kind(genre) I develop a forehead(front) - end with angular and I wish used an api but I want that the api be used that by me, of the blow I owes process how? Already have you try to make that? You have a tuto young which explains how can it be done? or a course(price) on api rest?

Thank you a lot of your help(assistant) and good luck

Comment: This could be an interesting question, but I'm afraid a lot was lost in the translation. If this is indeed about symfony access control, have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/security/firewall.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this documents:

- https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html
- https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle
- https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

That are 3 Libraries for fontend->backend-Communication. 
I use them for our api's (front/backend + app).